# Does Canonical accept BTC/Bitcoins as donations?

Tags: canonical, bitcoin, donation

I was wondering if there is a way to donate with bitcoin to Canonical? I would love to donate, but the only funds available to me now are bitcoins.

Answer (score 7):

No, not at the moment. This is the [current list](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Donation-accepting_organizations_and_projects) of organizations accepting bitcoins.

> **[Payment Methods](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/ubuntu-adds-new-donations-page)** (2012-10):
>
> So far only Paypal is the only accepted form of Payment. Canonical’s Jono Bacon says that this is only temporary and that ‘other payment mechanisms are currently being explored’.

If I was you I would drop him a message here: http://www.jonobacon.org/contact/

Comment: Jono Bacon is leaving Canonical on 29th May 2014. http://www.jonobacon.org/2014/05/19/goodbye-canonical-hello-xprize/